# How to make a koishele?

Tags: how-to, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

People use "*lulav* holders," or "[*koisheles*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47270/5323)," small containers of woven *lulav* leaves to hold their *lulav* sets (*lulav* + *hadass* + *arava*) together, as seen in the picture below.

[image: A basket consisting of tubes on either side containing the hadass and arava and a hole in the middle that the lulav fits through]

My father showed me how to make "*lulav* rings," those rings that hold the *koishele* (if that's what we're going to call it) together (not shown in the above picture), but those are pretty easy to make.

**How does one weave a *koishele* out of *lulav* leaves?**

Comment: I might post a Q/A set on making *lulav* rings, but I'd need to get my hands on some leaves for pictures -- I'd much rather do it that way than by pure text. *This* question, however, is something that I've been wondering for a while.

Comment: (*though I won't make you write an answer with pure text; if you want to wait till Sukkos, then go for it* :P)

Comment: Please do write one on the rings! I can *never* remember how to do them.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8cCtE3sPTs

Comment: @Scimonster It'll have to wait until Sukkos, unless you can give me a lulav *today* :P

Comment: @Shokhet, are you in Israel? If so, can't you find date palm fronds throughout the year (I honestly don't know).

Comment: I'm in the USA, @NoachmiFrankfurt. I don't know about Israel, but I do know that Florida has a lot of palm trees around.

Comment: FWIW, I've decided that I'm not going to bother with a koishele next year. It's a huge pain (and I know how to make the loops) so I'm just going to make individual loops for the haddasim and aravot to keep them in place on either side of the lulav and bind them on that way.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt The guy who sells you lulavim doesn't also give you a koishele with it? Every daled minim seller I've been to does that.

Comment: @Shokhet, in Boston, the only seller gives us a choice. I've always gotten mine with, but the eged around the koishele always causes a distraction. I actually took mine off on the second day because it was really taking up too much space in my hand (during hoshannot, my family holds all of the minim in the right hand so as to accommodate a siddur or machzor in the left)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Whatever works, I guess. AFAIK, nobody thinks that a koishele is *required*, though you should check out the question I linked to (*which I just noticed you asked yourself* ;-)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unx7GKTimhg

Answer (score 3):

Here are 2 YouTube videos that seem easy enough to follow:

- [One with Hebrew subtitles](https://youtu.be/z8cCtE3sPTs), no sound, 6.5 minutes.
- [One with Hebrew voice](https://youtu.be/kvLACAH6U6A), no subtitles. 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an Instructable with clear pictures and text instructions:

https://www.instructables.com/Lulav-Holder/